# Choosing language for creating a tasks management web app

Tags: mysql, task

i am a rookie in web development and i would like to make a start with the creation of a task management web app. In details i want the user to be able to create new tasks and then list those in a table and be able to print them. All data should be stored in a mysql database(i use XAMPP for example).

So what language/s is the most proper for this kind of job?

Thank you.

Comment: bit of an opinoun piece. but use php - it has the wisdom of the crowds ( anything you can think of can and has been done and is on a blog somewhere )

Comment: @amdixon And on StackOverflow for that matter

Comment: you know what they say about opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I would go PHP and especially CakePHP.

CakePHP is PHP framework that makes coding much easier and reduces amount of code needed as it includes commonly used components for every web-application.

You just need to grab a copy of source, define you database with CakePHP convention rules and run from command line "cake bake all" and you are mostly done with those requirements. Bake creates creates models, controllers and views for you with create, update, read and delete navigation links for every item in different lists.

Find out about CakePHP from [www.cakephp.org](http://cakephp.org) and documentation from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html

You can also take a look other frameworks too. Zend, Laravel, Codeigniter etc.

This might also help you to understand benefits of frameworks: http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/top-10-reasons-why-you-should-use-a-php-framework

Comment: what advantage would you put on cakePHP over say codeigniter or zend ?

Comment: Actually I have no experience on those, so cant really say. I can only speak on my experience with CakePHP and I have to say, it has made my life lot easier.

Actually it is everyone to decide, which to use. I think it all ends up to question "which one has most proper tools for me" and "which one has most understable doumentation for me"

Answer (score 0):

Well.. You installed xampp, so you're heading towards developing in PHP. Choosing a framework is just a matter of taste really, and ofcourse related to your application goal.

In your case for this Cake will do fine, but so will Laravel, Symfony2, Silex, CodeIgnitor, etc. You actually have a lot options here, you could also try node.js, see: https://nodejs.org/, which is javascript based.

Each one of the above frameworks as well as node.js have **a lot** of tutorials on creating a task/todo app.

Just pick one and start coding :)